# Streaming Couchbase data to S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, couchbase

I'd like to stream the contents of a couchbase bucket to S3 in parquet file using a spark job. I'm currently leveraging Couchbase's [spark streaming integration](https://docs.couchbase.com/spark-connector/current/spark-streaming.html) with the couchbase connector to generate a Dstream, but within each dstream there are multiple RDDs that only contain around 10 records each. I could create a file for each RDD and upload them individually to s3, but considering that I have 12 million records to import I would be left with around a million small files in s3 which is not ideal. What would be the best way to load the contents of a couchbase bucket and load it into s3 using a spark job? I'd ultimately like to have a single parquet file with all the contents of the couchbase bucket if possible.